# Uploading 4032x3024 / 12MP resolution camera image to server

Tags: android

I recently found out why a previous issue I had with photos from the rear camera on my phone not uploading via my Android app was occurring. The camera resolution was too high at 4032 x 3024 and the megapixel count was 12MP, but I noticed when I lower those qualities, it will work. It seems I can only go as high as the 4.7 megapixel quality. Is the 12MP quality just absolutely too large? Or is there a way to reduce that size before it is uploaded?

Main Activity

```
package com.example.stins.orbotcamera;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import net.gotev.uploadservice.MultipartUploadRequest;
import net.gotev.uploadservice.UploadNotificationConfig;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Uri file;
    private GPSTracker gps;
    private EditText imageComment;
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    private TextView imageLat, imageLong;
    private String mLat, mLong;

    public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://192.168.1.77/UploadExamples/upload.php";

    private Bitmap bitmap;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageComment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.imageComment);
        imageLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageLat);
        imageLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageLong);

        fab.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            fab.setEnabled(false);
            imageComment.setEnabled(false);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 0);
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                fab.setEnabled(true);
                imageComment.setEnabled(true);
            }

            else{
                coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
                final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout, "Accept all permissions to use app", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                snackbar.setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                                .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

                snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);


                snackbar.show();
        }


        }

    }



    public void uploadImage() {
        //getting name for the image
        String name = imageComment.getText().toString().trim();

        //getting the actual path of the image
        String path = getPath(file);


        //Uploading code
        try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            //Creating a multi part request
            new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                    .addParameter("name", name) //Adding text parameter to the request
                    .addParameter("latitude", mLat)
                    .addParameter("longitude", mLong)
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

            Log.d("Upload", "uploadImage: " + path);

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        String document_id = null;
        if (cursor != null) {
            document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        }
        if (document_id != null) {
            document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        }
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        String path = null;
        if (cursor != null) {
            path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        }
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }

        return path;
    }










    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            file = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), file);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageComment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



        if (requestCode == 0) {
            gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                     mLat = Double.toString(latitude);
                     mLong = Double.toString(longitude);

                    imageLat.setText(mLat);
                    imageLong.setText(mLong);

                    // \n is for new line
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
                     final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(coordinatorLayout, "Current location recorded", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

                    snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                    TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_location_on_white_24dp,0,0,0);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);


                    snackbar.show();
                } else {
                    // Can't get location.
                    // GPS or network is not enabled.
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings.

                }

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
                final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout,"Picture Cancelled", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);

                View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_cancel_white_24dp,0,0,0);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                snackbar.show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
                final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout,"Error Taking Picture", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);

                View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_error_outline_white_24dp,0,0,0);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                snackbar.show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_send:
                if(imageView.getDrawable()==null){
                    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
                    final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(coordinatorLayout,"Sorry, you'll need an image for that!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);

                    View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                    TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_error_outline_white_24dp,0,0,0);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    snackbar.show();
                }
                else {
                    uploadImage();
                }
                return true;


        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert)
                .setTitle("Exit")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close Orbot Camera?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i;
        if(v.getId()==R.id.fab)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 0);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "not uploading" means. What *precisely* are your symptoms?

Comment: Okay so my application's function is to choose an image from the device and display it in an ImageView. This image can then be uploaded to a server, with the database table receiving a hyperlink to the file, and an uploads folder receiving the actual .JPG or .PNG file. The hyperlink  goes to the table just fine, but when I try to copy the link into the browser to check it, I get "Object Not Found" error message. It does not go to the uploads folder either. this occurs when the megapixel quality (and possibly resolution is higher than about 5 megapixels.

Comment: What evidence do you have that the problem is on the Android side, rather than on your server?

Comment: Well I am only using a localhost server running via Xampp on my laptop to test the app. I haven't altered any server settings with it. Could this possibly be a some kind size limit issue that needs to be altered?